# CasaOS - Portainer - Graphical UI

Tags: docker, portainer

I’m running casaos on my raspberry pi4, accessing it through the web ui. Ive installed portainer on it aswell and through portainer, installer ubuntu.

Id like to access a graphical ui on ubuntu, is it possible to access a graphical ui without installing tight vnc etc?

Any tips on casaos is welcome as id like to install multiple operating systems and access them through a graphical ui

Ive tried accessing the ui using the ip, no luck.